# Redux: Normalizing Global State

Tags: reactjs, redux

Assume the following situation:

```
1. Page has many posts
2. Post has many comments
```

I have the following reducers:

```
1. PagesReducer
2. PostsReducer
3. PostReducer
4. CommentsReducer
```

I have the following state right now:

```
pagesByTitle: {
  dorrisPage: {
    isFetching: false,
    data: {
      _id: "..."
      title: "dorrisPage",
    },
    posts: [
      {
        isFetching: false,
        data: {
          _id: "..",
          body: ".."
        },
        comments: [..]
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above structure looked okay initially, but I realized that I had to pass down the `action` for child states. For example, if I dispatched an action called

```
ADD_COMMENT
```

I would pass the action down to `PagesReducer`, `PostsReducer`, `PostReducer`, and `CommentsReducer`, and finally the `CommentsReducer` will handle that action. I think this is when I realized why *normalizing states* is recommended in Redux.

Can you help me with the following questions?

1. Is my motivation for normalizing states correct in this context?
2. What's the best way to normalize the example states?

Answer (score 1):

**you should avoid nesting**.

quote from redux docs:

> In a more complex app, you’re going to want different entities to
>   reference each other. We suggest that you keep your state as
>   normalized as possible, without any nesting. Keep every entity in an
>   object stored with an ID as a key, and use IDs to reference it from
>   other entities, or lists. Think of the app’s state as a database. This
>   approach is described in normalizr's documentation in detail.

For normalize state you can use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

```
pages:{
    items:{
        1:{id: 1,title: "dorrisPage", posts:[33,57]}
        2:{id: 2, title: "anotherPage",posts:[57]}
    },
    isFetching: false,
    itemIds:[1,2,..]
},
posts:{
    items:{
        33:{id: 33,title: "Post33", comments:[1,2]}
        57:{id: 57, title: "Post57", comments:[]}
    },
    isFetching: false,
    itemIds:[33,57,..]
}
comments:{
    items:{
        1:{id: 1, user: "user1", text:"fds"}
        2:{id: 2, user: "user2", text:"fds2"}
    },
    isFetching: false,
    itemIds:[1,2,..]
}
```

**"itemIds" is neccessary for items ordering**

then reducers may look like this

```
export const posts = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case type.FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST:
        case type.FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE:
            return {...state, isFetching: action.isFetching};
        case type.FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
        return {...state,
            isFetching: action.isFetching,
            items: action.entities.posts, itemsIds: action.result
        };

        case type.DELETE_POST:
        return {...state,
            items: omit(state.items, action.id),
            itemsIds: state.itemsIds.filter(id=>id !== action.id)
        };
        case type.UPDATE_POST:
        return {...state, items: {...state.items,
                [action.post.id]: {...state.items[action.post.id],...action.post}}};

        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

**much easier to query post by id:**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) =({
    post:state.posts.items[ownProps.id]
})
```

**for computing derived data from redux store, you can use [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) for creating memoized, composable selector functions**

[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCQ0ZSr-a2o)